# Why is my sanitized img tags coming up empty?

Tags: angularjs

The following code is a function that uses parameters. When I alert the variable, the string appears exactly how it is supposed to.

```
$scope.createMap = function(size,scale,center,zoom,style){
     $scope.myMap = "<img ng-src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size="+size+"&scale="+scale+"&center=IL"+center+"&style="+style+"&zoom="+zoom+"'>";
     alert($scope.myMap);

     return;
}
```

However, on the HTML page where this is binded to:

```
<div ng-bind-html="myMap" id="myStaticMap">
    MAP GOES HERE
</div>
```

The area is empty and when I "inspect element" there is `<img></img>`, so it is registering it is an image, but coming up empty.

Same thing happens here:

```
$scope.displayPage = function(page){
        $scope.siteName = $scope.names[page].PageName;
        $scope.logo = "<img ng-src='"+$scope.names[page].logo+"'>";
        alert($scope.logo);

        $scope.createMap($scope.names[page].Size,$scope.names[page].Scale,$scope.names[page].Center,$scope.names[page].Zoom,$scope.names[page].Style);}
```

Where the parameter is being used a little bit differently. But again, the alert for `$scope.logo` is alerting the correct string but there is `<img></img>` where it is supposed to be binded. `$scope.siteName` is binded fine, but then, it is not binding any HTML.

I am using the sanitize module:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngSanitize"]);
```

(the script is placed last in my list of external references)

So I am not sure what is wrong here.

---

UPDATE: So I did the suggestion in answer below and it is working when I change `ng-src` to `src` so that is awesome. However, I am getting the error below in my web console, anyone know why? I get it whether I use `ng-src` or `src`:

> "Error: html.indexOf is not a function
>   htmlParser@http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.3/angular-sanitize.js:205:12
>   $sanitize@http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.3/angular-sanitize.js:119:1
>   ngBindHtmlWatchAction@http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.3/angular-sanitize.js:420:1
>   Yd/this.$gethttps://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:110:371
>   Yd/this.$gethttps://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:113:360
>   m@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:72:452
>   w@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:77:463
>   ye/https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:79:24

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngSanitize"]);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http, $sce) {
```

Comment: you need to make image url as `trustedResourceUrl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you parse html from within your controller, you have to use the `$sce` dependency from angular, in order to mark the html as "trusted":

```
angular.module("yourModule").controller("yourController",
    ["$scope", "$sce", function ($scope, $sce) {
        $scope.displayPage = function(page){
        $scope.siteName = $scope.names[page].PageName;
        $scope.logo = $sce.trustAsHtml("<img ng-src='"+$scope.names[page].logo+"'>");
        alert($scope.logo);
        $scope.createMap($scope.names[page].Size,$scope.names[page].Scale,$scope.names[page].Center,$scope.names[page].Zoom,$scope.names[page].Style);}
    }
]);
```

Comment: I will mark this as answer once I decipher if this next issue is related or not: it is now showing the html in "inspect element" but the view is otherwise blank, nothing shows up, not even saying if like the image does not exist.

Comment: Oh and just noticed an error, I will place in my question.

Comment: It's possible that the digest cycle isn't parsing your ng-src directive